# Can python doctest ignore some output lines?

Tags: python, doctest

I'd like to write a doctest like this:

```
"""
>>> print a.string()
          foo : a
          bar : b
         date : <I don't care about the date output>
          baz : c
"""
```

Is there any way to do this?  I think it would make more sense to switch to unittest, but I'm curious whether it's possible to specify a range of output that shouldn't be matched for the test in doctest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With `doctest.ELLIPSIS`, you can use `...` to mean "match any string here". You can set `doctest` options with a doctest directive, to make it active for just one test case: one example in the [online docs](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) is:

```
>>> print range(20) # doctest:+ELLIPSIS
[0, 1, ..., 18, 19]
```

If you want a doctest option to be active throughout, you can pass it as the `optionflags=` argument to whatever doctest functions you use, e.g. `doctest.testfile`. (You can pass multiple option flags there by using the `|` operator to bit-or them).

Comment: But how can we ignore the whole line?

Comment: @t0ster, just put `...` as the whole of the "expected output" (with `doctest.ELLIPSIS` set, of course), and doctest will accept any content on that output line, i.e. "ignore the whole line" of output.

Comment: "ignore the whole line" as above does not work since doctest confuses the ellipsis with a (python) continuation of the previous line. I could not find any way to ignore the whole line. Actually, I was looking for "ignore the whole output".

Comment: @RomanDolgiy and phaedrus: if you don't care about side effects, use doctest.SKIP.  If you do care about side effects, then there's no great solutions, but in a separate answer below, I wrote up some ways to make it work if you really need it.

Comment: @RomanDolgiy **Q**: *how can we ignore the whole line?* **A**: don't print the line

Answer (score 20):

Responding to questions about "how can we ignore the whole line": yes, the fact that "..." also looks like a continuation like makes it hard to ignore the entire output.  You can use "#doctest: +SKIP" if you just want to skip the example entirely, but that won't work if you are relying on its side-effects.  If you *really* need to do this, I suppose you could monkey-patch the doctest module itself, though I wouldn't particularly recommend it:

```
>>> import doctest
>>> doctest.ELLIPSIS_MARKER = '-etc-'
>>> print 12 # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
-etc-
```

(this test passes.)

Or you could temporarily suppress stdout and/or stderr:

```
>>> # Suppress stdout
>>> import sys
>>> class DevNull:
...     def noop(*args, **kwargs): pass
...     close = write = flush = writelines = noop
>>> sys.stdout = DevNull()
>>> # Run a test and ignore output (but we need its side effects)
>>> print 12 # NOTE: stdout is suppressed!
>>> # Restore stdout
>>> sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

(this test also passes.)

Comment: Python 3 [**`io.TextIO.write`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) now returns the number of characters written.

Answer (score 15):

I found it easier to simply assign the unneeded return values to a variable:

```
>>> _ = do_something()
>>> check_something()
True
```

Answer (score 12):

Ignoring the whole line is bit tricky though. Here:

```
"""
>>> do_your_thing() #doctest:+ELLIPSIS
...
"""
```

The triple dot will be interpreted as line continuation, and cause a syntax error.

If you want to ignore the whole line, you'll need something like:

```
"""
>>> sys.stdout.write('skip from here '); do_your_thing() #doctest:+ELLIPSIS
skip from here ...
"""
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write tuples before and after your function (hack inspired by answer of Mark Horvath):

```
def foo():
    """
    >>> ();foo();() # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    (...)
    """
    print "Hello world"
    return "Hello world"
```

Comment: I like this one the most. Uses Mark's trick without needing to import another module just for doctest. Great idea!

Answer (score 0):

[Can I have an ellipsis at the beginning of the line in a Python doctest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812833/can-i-have-an-ellipsis-at-the-beginning-of-the-line-in-a-python-doctest) explains how to create a custom output checker that uses an additional string as an ellipsis.  This would let you write the following, while still used '...' elsewhere.

```
def foo():
  """
  >>> foo() # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
  [...] world
  """
  print "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python3 I found it easier to just check if the outputs you want are being shown, easier to explain with an example:

```
def some_function():
    '''
    blah blah blah explaining function
    example:
    >>>something_you_want in some_function()
    True
    '''
```

super easy to implement and beginner friendly.