# Alternative results in doctests

Tags: python, doctest

I have a doctest where I test a float conversion:

```
>>> float('fish')
```

In Python < 2.7 this results in:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): fish
```

In Python 2.7 the result is

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: fish
```

Can I make both these results acceptable in my doctest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [doctest.IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL) option.  The documentation has a good example of how to use it.  You can also use the [ellipsis](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS) constant in the doctest like a wildcard.

Something like this as the doctest:

```
>>> float('fish')
ValueError:...
```

You can see Alex Martellis post about this same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024411/can-python-doctest-ignore-some-output-lines/1024426#1024426).

Comment: Now that's a great use for ellipsis (which is a constant singleton, however!)

Answer (score 3):

Yes with something like this :

```
>>> float('fish') #doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError:
```

look [here](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL) for why.