# How to check output starting with ellipsis in Python's doctests

Tags: python, testing, doctest

I have a method which outputs `......silence......` to represent no activity:

```
def silence(self):
     print('......silence......')
```

I have the following doctest written for the method:

```
>>> s = SmokeDetector()
>>> s.silence()
.......silence......
```

But when I run the doctest, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: line 4 of the docstring for smoke_detector4.SmokeDetector.silence lacks blank after ...: '.......silence......'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have an ellipsis at the beginning of the line in a Python doctest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812833/can-i-have-an-ellipsis-at-the-beginning-of-the-line-in-a-python-doctest)