# How do I enable 'doctest.ELLIPSIS' at the Python prompt?

Tags: python, ipython, command-prompt, interactive, doctest

I often [see examples](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) that use `doctest.ELLIPSIS` to limit output in [interactive examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024426/656912) of Python use,

```
>>> print range(20) # doctest:+ELLIPSIS
[0, 1, ..., 18, 19]
```

and see here how to enable the feature in modules; but I can't figure out how to enable this feature interactvely.

How do I enable `doctest.ELLIPSIS` at the Python or IPython prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not limiting the output, it's telling doctest it doesn't need to check all of it. That line of code will still produce the full output:

```
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

But doctest will only check the bits before and after the `...`.

I don't know of anything to limit the output like that in interactive sessions, though if you use Python 3, you could write your own implementation of `print()` to do it.

Comment: Exactly - the ELLIPSIS flag affects checking the output, not producing it.