# How to ignore the whole output of an instruction using python doctest?

Tags: python-3.6, ellipsis, doctest

Ellispis does not seem to work to ignore the whole output line.
I'd like to ignore **everything** that is outputed by `foo`:

```py
def foo():
    """                                                                                
    >>> foo() # doctest: +ELLIPSIS                                                     
    ...                                                                          
    """
    print("IGNORE ME")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Running with python3 gives:

```
Failed example:
    foo() # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
Expected nothing
Got:
    IGNORE ME
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__.foo
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Note that ignoring **only part** of the output works. Adding a character before `...` (here "-"):

```py
def foo():
    """                                                                                
    >>> foo() # doctest: +ELLIPSIS                                                     
    -...                                                                          
    """
    print("-IGNORE ME")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can python doctest ignore some output lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024411/can-python-doctest-ignore-some-output-lines)

Comment: The question [Can python doctest ignore some output lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024411/can-python-doctest-ignore-some-output-lines) treats **some** lines among others, that indeed works well. Here it's about the **whole** output.